# Calling a function from a helper in Vue Template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Helper function I have ConvertToSome Function:

```
export function convertToSome(item) {
  item = item.toString();
  var qq = "qwqe";
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    item = item.split(i).join(qq[i]);
  }
  return item;
}
```

And In my Vue I have Component like this :

```
import { convertToSome } from '../../../helpers';
```

when I want to use this function in component I got this error :

```
TypeError: "_vm.convertToSome is not a function"
```

How can I use this function into template ?

Comment: how do you call that function?

Comment: {{convertToSome(somenumber)}}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your import statement (`import { convertToSome } from '../../../helpers';`) you could create a local method in your Vue instance and use the imported function inside:

```
  methods: {
    convertToSome(item) {
      // "convertToSome" inside is the imported function
      return convertToSome(item);
    }
  }
```

You can call `this.convertToSome(item)` anywhere in your script to call the Vue method which will use the imported function.

...or directly in your template:

`<div> {{ convertToSome(item) }} <div>`

You could also use the imported function as a `filter` (as proposed by @thanksd), which seems more suitable in your case:

```
  filters: {
    convertToSome(item) {
      return convertToSome(item);
    }
  },
```

...which you could use directly in your template:

`<div> {{ foo | convertToSome }} <div>`

Comment: Just my opinion, but in this case I'd make it a filter. You'd just need to add `filters: { convertToSome }` to the Vue definition object and then in your template you could use it like `{{ foo | convertToSome }}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot .

Answer (score 4):

Just assigned the imported function to a data property like below

```
import { convertToSome } from '../../../helpers';
```

Then in the data section;

```
data(){
    return {
      convertToSome: convertToSome
    }
}
```

Comment: won't work with parameter functions